# Add a value to bypass list of IE proxy

Tags: powershell, proxy

I am trying to add (append) a value to bypass list of IE proxy of multiple remote servers. But not getting any command line way to do it.

```
netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie
```

Comment: `netsh` is a native windows command line tool and isn't Powershell.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a community not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself.

Comment: I think I got you, I got the registry which has this information:
`"HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyOverride"`

Comment: I am not unwilling to write the code, was just unaware if there is a powershell method to do it. got the solution:
`$registryPath = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"`
`$value = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name ProxyOverride).ProxyOverride`
`$value += ";10.241.*"`
`Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name ProxyOverride -Value $value`